# Pandas: How to extract value from a row from describe() into a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

So if i wanted to get the count and store it as a variable z.
I know I can do something like df.describe().loc['count'] but i am unable to extract the number to variable z itself to do mathematical operations like addition.

Comment: if you want an individual stat, you can just use that particular method, e.g. `z = df['col'].count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas [describe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) method returns a Series or a DataFrame.

So, you can extract and assign any specific value like this (although it is easier to use the corresponding method, as suggested by @tdy):

```py
z = df.describe().loc["50%"].tolist()[0]

print(type(z))  # <class 'float'>
```